# My else statement doesn't seem to function(JAVA)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Whativelearned {

    enum MyfirstEnum {one, two, three}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboardinput = new Scanner(in);
        MyfirstEnum trolley;
        char a1;

        out.println("Do you pee in the shower"? Y/N");
        a1 = keyboardinput.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);


        if (a1=='Y'||a1=='y') {
            trolley=MyfirstEnum.one;
            out.println("Ewwwwwww");
        }


        if (a1=='N'||a1=='n') {
            trolley=MyfirstEnum.two;
            out.println("Well somebody isn't being very honest");
        }else {
            out.println("You're not so keen on following instructions, are you?");
        }

        keyboardinput.close();
    }

}
```

I expect my `else` statement to cover all outcomes except for the cases in the `if` cases.
As I expect it to act as  `(!(a1=='Y'||(a1=='y'||a1=='n'||a2=='N'))`

but when I run it the listing the `else` statement seems to be executed in all cases.

Comment: Your else statement refers to the last `if` block only thus it gets triggered only when `(!(a1=='n'||a2=='N'))`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (a1=='Y' || a1=='y') {
    trolley=MyfirstEnum.one;
    out.println("Ewwwwwww");
} else if (a1=='N' || a1=='n') {
    trolley = MyfirstEnum.two;
    out.println("Well somebody isn't being very honest");
} else {
    out.println("You're not so keen on following instructions, are you?");
}
```

Comment: Even better with a switch statement:
`
switch(a1){ 
    case('Y'):
    case('y'): {
        trolley=MyfirstEnum.one;
        out.println("Ewwwwwww"); 
        break;
    }
    case('N'):
    case('n'): {
        trolley=MyfirstEnum.two;
        out.println("Well somebody isn't being very honest");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        out.println("You're not so keen on following instructions, are you?");
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is always specific to one `if` statement. Therefore, your `else` clause is executed whenever the last `if` condition is not met.

To execute your clause only when none of the conditions are met, you need to change your `if` statements to `else if` like so:

```
if (a1 == 'y' || a1 == 'Y') {
    // ...
} else if (a1 == 'n' || 'a1 == 'N') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ....
}
```

Another way to solve this would be using a `switch` statement. These are used to compare a variable to a set of constants. You can use them like this:

```
switch (a1) {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
        // ...
        break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // ...
}
```

Please read up some more about the `switch` statement before you try it in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `else` befor second `for` loop:

```
else if (a1=='N'||a1=='n') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Code execution is best understood by a dry run.

1. If you do in your code you will find the first `if` statement is checked and if its true then its corresponding process is executed.
2. Now control moves down to execute the next `if` statement. This `if` statement checks the condition which os mutually exclusive of the above `if`. if its true (only in case above is false) then its corresponding process is executed and if its false then the `else` part process is executed.

You need to use `if` followed by `if else` followed by `else`